# If there is an invariant measure, is it necessarily unique (up to a constant multi- plication)?

Tags: probability

When I was doing an exercise " When $(X_n)$ is irreducible Markov chain, If there is a reversible measure, is it necessarily unique (up to a constant multiplication)?" The answer is yes, and the proof is simple as $\mu(x)p^{(n)}(x,y)= \mu(y)p^{(n)}(y,x) \, \forall n$.

But I cannot prove or disprove the similar question for invariant measure " When $(X_n)$ is irreducible Markov chain, If there is in invariant measure, is it necessarily unique (up to a constant multiplication)?".

There is a theorem stating that when $(X_n)$ is recurrent the answer is yes, but what about general conditions? Can someone provide an example or a proof? Thanks in advance!

Update: Here the invariant measure should not be zero measure, and the measure should be nonnegative but can have infinite mass over the whole contable state space $S$.

Comment: Can your measure take a mixture of positive and negative values?

Comment: @Henry No, it is just nonnegative measure but can have infinite mass over the whole set $S$

Comment: Then I cannot find a counter example.  Allowing negative measure would allow the example of a balanced random  walk on $\mathbb Z$ (so each step is $\pm1$ with probability $\frac12$) with the measures $\mu_a(x)=1$ or $\mu_b(x)=x$

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one *probability* measure.
However, multiple invariant measures are possible.

Consider example 9.2.17 in Douc, R., Moulines, E., Priouret, P. & Soulier, P. Markov Chains. (Springer, 2018):

> Let $p \in (0,1)\setminus\{1/2\}$ and consider the following chain:
> $$X_{n+1} = \begin{cases} X_n + 1 & \text{with probability } p \\ X_n - 1 & \text{with probability } 1-p \end{cases}.$$
> Then $\lambda_0(k) = 1$ and $\lambda_1(k) = ((1-p)/p)^k$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$ are both invariant.